# How to remove Page template from a SPFx webpart that does not exist any more?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

In list shown in Page templates under Apps I see Featured 7 squares each representing a "SharePointFullPage" webpart.
I need to remove one of them but the "Delete from site" does not delete.
The "Go to template" takes me to the URL:

```
/_layouts/15/AppPageHost.aspx?mode=preview&componentId=22301a6c-e808-4235-b05c-54cc39462003&preconfiguredEntryId=0
```

How can I get rid of it?
Is there a PnP PowerShell command to do it?
Thank you